# Failed to start default.target: Operation refused unit may not be isolated

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-stretch

I tried to start my Raspberry this morning and I have this error message:
Failed to start default.target: Operation refused, unit may not be isolated.
Yet last night I plugged my raspberry for the first time to my screen with Raspbian mounted on a micro SD card. And it worked very well.

Is there anyone who knows raspberry and raspbian well and who could help me?

Comment: Did you change any system settings last time you booted? Also, you might consider just rewriting  your SD card if there's nothing important on there to save yourself time if you can't figure out the issue.

Comment: I have reinstalled raspbian. Fortunately I thought about it almost immediately after posting. And it works well. Thank you for the help.